# Facebook Marketing API Accessing Insights

Tags: java, facebook, sdk, ads

I am trying to access information about my Campaign but I am having trouble with getting cpc, cpv etc. I am using java facebook ads sdk and implementing it in my java application.

This helps me getting today spends:

```
System.out.println(account.getInsights().setDatePreset(com.facebook.ads.sdk.AdsInsights.EnumDatePreset.VALUE_LAST_3_DAYS).execute().get(0).getFieldSpend());
```

And it is working fine. But what I need is more information, like inline clicks etc. This command returns null and I am not able to get any of those:

```
System.out.println(account.getInsights().setDatePreset(com.facebook.ads.sdk.AdsInsights.EnumDatePreset.VALUE_LAST_3_DAYS).execute().get(0).getFieldInlineLinkClicks());
```

Same is for `getFieldCpc()` and others. Pleas help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly request the fields you want.

Try to put ".requestField("inline_link_clicks")" before "execute()".